# java.sql.ARRAY to ArrayList<String[]> OracleCallableStatement

Tags: java, sql, arrays, oracle, object

I'm getting an `ARRAY` from `oralce sql in java` and write it to `java.sql.ARRAY`. This array is type of `VARRAY` of `OBJECT`. How can I convert this type to ArrayList?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you actually are getting an array of `String[]`, you should be able to use something like -

```
public static List<String[]> getList(ResultSet rs) throws IOException, SQLException {
    List<String[]> al = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    java.sql.Array z = rs.getArray("my_array_column");
    for (Object obj : (Object[])z.getArray()) {
        try {
            String [] arr = (String[]) obj;
            al.add(arr);
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            System.out.println("Object is not a String[]");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return al;
}
```

Comment: if I use `ResultSet` it would work, but I'm using `JDBC and OracleCallableStatement` and when i convert `ARRAY` to `Object` it' OK, but when i try to convert it to String I'm getting an error  `java.lang.ClassCastException: oracle.sql.STRUCT cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;`

Comment: Please be specific in your question. Now, what do you mean by "convert", that exception is from an invalid "cast"; that is not a conversion.